# OLE Structured storage equivalent

Tags: ole, structured-storage

I want to store some large amount of Data alonmg with some texts and nuber fileds into one file. 
I have used structured OLE in the past, and I have liked it. But it seems like a pretty old technology now. I have also considered using HDF File format 
http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/

But it does not support Single Write Multiple Read from different machines. Need a scalable storage, that is file based.

Are there any other simple File formats that I can use, that are identical to this but that are fast and easy to implement ?

Shashi